# Mongodb use find (not aggregation) to get only one nested sub-document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my collection I have two nested sub-documents, respectively called "levels" and "modules":

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "course": "course1",
    "levels": [
      {
        "level_id": "C1L1",
        "name": "course 1 - level1",
        "modules": [
          {
            "module_id": "C1L1M1",
            "name": "level 1module1"
          },
          {
            "module_id": "C1L1M2",
            "name": "level 1 module2"
          },
          
        ]
      },
      {
        "level_id": "C1L2",
        "name": "course 1 - level2",
        "modules": [
          {
            "module_id": "C1L2M1",
            "name": "level 2 module1"
          },
          {
            "module_id": "C1L1M2",
            "name": "level 2 module2"
          },
          
        ]
      },
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "course": "course2",
    "levels": [
      {
        "level_id": "C2L1",
        "name": "course 2 - level1",
        "modules": [
          {
            "module_id": "C2L1M1",
            "name": "level1 module1"
          },
          {
            "module_id": "C2L1M2",
            "name": "level1 module2"
          },
          
        ]
      },
      {
        "level_id": "C2L2",
        "name": "course 2 - level2",
        "modules": [
          {
            "module_id": "C2L2M1",
            "name": "level 2 module1"
          },
          {
            "module_id": "C2L1M2",
            "name": "level 2 module2"
          },
          
        ]
      },
      
    ]
  },
]
```

I need to get only one sub-document that matches criteria, for example `{"module_id": "C1L2M1"}` .
I already know exactly how to achieve this using the aggregation framework, but I want to know if there is any solution avoiding aggregation.

I can retrieve only one nested sub-document using `$elemMatch` inside the projection, but I can't figure out how to filter the second nested sub-document (modules, in my example).

My desired result is query module "C1L2M1" and get only this:

```
{
  "module_id": "C1L2M1",
  "name": "level 2 module1"
}
```

Here an example playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/uwBOh1MkQm-

Comment: *I want to know if there is any solution avoiding aggregation* => no it is not possible without aggregation filter operators, you can use aggregation projection operators in find projection starting from MongoDB 4.4. like $map/$filter..

Comment: That's what I taught. It's possible in >= 4.4 right?

Comment: @turivishal thanks, do u know if using aggregation operator inside find projection is faster or slower (or equal :) ) in terms of performance?

Comment: i think both are equal, they have not mention in [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/), if you want to make sure 100%  then check performance by .explain() in both queries.

Comment: @turivishal thank you very much. Do you want to post the answer so I can accept it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I want to know if there is any solution avoiding aggregation.*

There is no other option except aggregation, To achieve your expected result you must have to use [Aggregation Array Expression Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#array-expression-operators).

---

If you really want to use `find` methods then you can use [Aggregation Expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#use-aggregation-expression) starting from MongoDB 4.4,

> Starting in MongoDB 4.4, as part of making `find()` and `findAndModify()` projection consistent with aggregation's `$project` stage,
> The `find()` and `findAndModify()` projection can accept aggregation expressions and syntax. 
> MongoDB enforces additional restrictions with regards to projections. See [Projection Restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Projection-Restrictions) for details.

---

> *do u know if using aggregation operator inside find projection is faster or slower (or equal :) ) in terms of performance?*

As per [find-projection-documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection) there is no any specification about performance, but i think both are equal.

If you really want to check the performance of both methods then you can check by [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/) executionStats mode.

Answer (score 1):

here's an unreadable mess that get's the result you want using `find` command:

```
db.collection.find(
{
    "levels.modules.module_id": "C1L2M1"
},
{
    _id: 0,
    module: {
        $first: {
            $filter: {
                input: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$levels",
                        as: "l",
                        in: {
                            $first: {
                                $filter: {
                                    input: "$$l.modules",
                                    as: "m",
                                    cond: { $eq: ["$$m.module_id", "C1L2M1"] }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                as: "x",
                cond: { $ne: ["$$x", null] }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

it outputs the following:

```
{
    "module" : {
        "module_id" : "C1L2M1",
        "name" : "level 2 module1"
    }
}
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/KZHwvKdgY9f